# jira oauth base url

Tags: oauth, jira, jira-rest-api

My client application allows to connect to several third party data sources to obtain data from, and JIRA is one of them. Oauth in my client application is handled in such a way that for each data source, it accepts constant values for request token url, access token url, authorization url, client ID and secret and obtains an access token. From the [JIRA OAuth example](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-oauth-authentication), the first 3 values are dependent on the BASE URL. Is the BASE URL always different for each company/business that uses JIRA? However, values for these fields are constant for Twitter, Facebook etc.
Also, what configuration changes should the company admin who has a JIRA account that wants to allow access from my application have to make? Should each business admin configure an application link to allow access from my application?

Comment: JIRA baseUrl contains the JIRA url part which is always the same on THIS jira instance. So if JIRA is at `https://issues.apache.org/jira` that's the baseUrl. Every instance of JIRA has another baseUrl.

Comment: @Joromo, if my OAuth tokens are associated with a baseURL, does that mean that I am only authorized to access information from that Jira instance through rest API calls?

Comment: I'm not into this topic but I wanted to help you just a little bit. Your link seems to be pretty detailed. It contains an java example of doing an OAuth request, you should understand and try it. [link]https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/files/6291692/rest-oauth-client-1.0-sources.jar As said in the source this is done by a HTTP request, so I think rest isn't neccesary for you.